# Is there a way to demonstrate strength of a Hierarchical Bayesian Model versus a non-Hierarchical Bayesian Model on simulated data?

Tags: bayesian, simulation, hierarchical-bayesian

Is there a way to demonstrate strength of a Hierarchical Bayesian Model versus a non-Hierarchical Bayesian Model on simulated data?

I'm ideally looking for a plot that shows that a Hierarchical Bayesian Model better succeeds in detecting a difference/effect against a non-Hierarchical Bayesian Model as we keep decreasing the amount of data.

An effect is detected if the pairwise difference between estimated quantities is $> 0$ with probability $0.95$. So this can be calculated from both the models.

Is there a way to demonstrate this using simulated data?

Comment: Sure, we can demonstrate that. Just set-up a situation where many units are similar, when borrowing information will help (vs. estimating separate parameters for each unit). Or is there some specific difficulty with it?